# is not a valid virtual path in SiteMap

Tags: c#, asp.net, email-attachments

hello i want to send an mail of image from Asp.net.

i got an error like this :: 'http://domain-name.com/slideshow/original/Jellyfish.png'  is not a valid virtual path.

my code is :

```
 try
    {
        string _SenderEmailID = ReciverEmailID.Text.ToString();
        string _ReciverEmailID = ReciverEmailID.Text.ToString();
        string _Sender = FullName.Text.ToString();
        string post = "JellyBeans.png";
        string ImagePath = "http://www.domain-name.com/slideshow/original/";
        string iImage = ImagePath + post;
        img1.ImageUrl = ImagePath;

        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

        mail.To.Add(_ReciverEmailID);
        mail.From = new MailAddress(_SenderEmailID);

        mail.Subject = _Sender + " sent you a mail from 'www.domain-name.com";
        string Body = "<img alt=\"\" hspace=0 src=\"cid:imageId\" align=baseline border=0 >";
        AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(Body, null, "text/html");
        LinkedResource imagelink = new LinkedResource(Server.MapPath(ImagePath)+  @post, "image/png");
        imagelink.ContentId = "imageId";
        imagelink.TransferEncoding = System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.Base64;
        htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(imagelink);
        mail.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.PickupDirectoryFromIis;
        smtp.Send(mail);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove

```
Server.MapPath
```

from the line

```
LinkedResource imagelink = new LinkedResource(Server.MapPath(ImagePath)+  @post, "image/png");
```

[Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx) is used when the path is in your application, a virtual path. Your image url is a direct url or physical path so `MapPath` is not needed.

> Returns the physical file path that corresponds to the specified
>   virtual path on the Web server.

You would use `MapPath` if your image was in your VisualStudio solution.

Comment: when i remove Server.MapPath from LinkedResource imagelink = new LinkedResource(iImage, "image/png");

now i face new error like : URI formats are not supported while. @Sam Leach

Comment: Can you put the image on your web server?

Comment: What's the path of the image? Use that path. Not the external domain name but the physical path on the server. Or use Server.MapPath to get the physical path from the virtual path. The virtual path might be "~/Images/JellyBeans.png". Is that clear? The physical path might be "C:/Images/JellyBeans.png"

Comment: but i want to send image from Live site !

Comment: image from local computer is been send 
but image form website cannot send through this code